# How to avoid "Possible Flow Control Vulnerability" in php?

Tags: php, security, checkmarx

I am getting a security vulnerability - Possible Flow Control [Severity - Low]
with Checkmarx Scan for the following PHP code. 
Giving  error on using IF or isset() 
[image]

[image]

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're relying on the raw value of the POST variable for flow control (i.e. deciding which code to execute). This is a risk (all be it a low one) because an attacker can potentially force your code to execute code at their discretion or in ways you might not have anticipated.

It's hard to know if this is actually a problem for you with out seeing the entire code at work here, only you can know for sure. It's not something you need to change or fix per se, just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you need to check that the $_POST data exists at the index before you access it.

```
if (empty($_POST['maintDetail']))
   return;
 $myVar = $_POST['mainDetails'];//safe!
```

For the second code block you posted, i'm not sure. Looks fine to me. Though you should check for `!empty` if you want there to be definite content there as an empty string will be technically set. Take a look at [this page](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/) if you want more information about that.

Comment: I will try this solution and get back to you with the output

Comment: @bulk i will use the filter_var inbuilt function to sanitize my post variable.